# Spring STS (STS) Conflicts with WebSphere Development Tools for Eclipse (Wasdev WDT) - Spring features disappear

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere, spring-tool-suite, websphere-liberty

My problem is that as soon as I add the WebSphere Developer Tools 8.5.5 for Mars into Spring STS some of the spring features disappear.  The first feature I noticed missing was "Spring Starter Project" under  Right Click -> New.  I thought it had just disappeared so I tried New -> Other and found that only "Spring Bean Configuration File" existed.

Any help in resolving this conflict is greatly appreciated.

I am using Spring STS in an environment where the I have some applications that deploy to a weblogic environment and other applications that deploy to a WebSphere environment.  I am trying to setup and environment that combines all the plugins I use into one development environment.

Here's the "what I think are relevant" parts of my configuration:
OS: RHEL 6.5
JDK: IBM 8.0.2.0
STS: 3.7.2 - full eclipse archive from spring tools website
WDT: 8.5.5.7 for Mars from the eclipse marketplace

Spring sts is installed on a partition mounted at /app
STS location is /app/devtools/sts-bundle
JDK is installed under /app/devtools/sts-bundle/sts-3.7.2.RELEASE/jre
WDT is installed using the eclipse marketplace

I have tried installing WDT into the "dropins" folder, but experience the same issue.

Thank's in advance.

P.S.  I would love to see a new tag "wdt" for the WebSphere Developer Tools for Eclipse [IBM WDT Download Page](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-WebSphere_Developer_Tools_for_Eclipse_Mars)

Comment: This sounds very much like an incompatibility between STS 3.7.2 and the WebSphere Developer Tools. I will try to see if I can reproduce this problem. In the meantime, I would like to recommend to file an issue for this via: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS to track progress.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue. It looks like the installation of those IBM tools somehow removes the javax.validation bundle, but doesn't offer another bundle that exports those packages. Not sure why though, that would be a question for the people at IBM. The removal of javax.validation causes some Spring IDE bundles to not resolve anymore. That is the reason why those features disappear... :-(

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.  I'll post a bug with the WDT team.  In the mean time, would the installation order matter?  Meaning if I start with a base eclipse install and use the marketplace to add WDT and then STS, would that overcome the problem?

Comment: FYI, I have also had problems with STS and the OEPE plugins from Oracle.

Comment: @MartinLippert I created bug STS-4821 but now realize it may not be a "Major" bug.  I also requested help from the ibm wasdev site @ https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/242245/websphere-development-tools-for-eclipse-wasdev-wdt.html

Comment: Not sure about the order, but we could give it a try. Lets continue the discussion in the issuetracker, thanks for filing that ticket: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4281